# Talking to an iPython kernel with Node.js -- no response to kernel_info_request

Tags: node.js, ipython

I'm sending a *kernel_info_request* to a running iPython kernel from a node.js script over the shell channel but I'm not getting a response. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the IPython connection file, ipker.json. Note that I set the *key* to *""* to avoid having to deal with signatures at this point.

```
{
  "stdin_port": 60304, 
  "ip": "127.0.0.1", 
  "control_port": 59733, 
  "hb_port": 39868, 
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256", 
  "key": "", 
  "shell_port": 51314, 
  "transport": "tcp", 
  "iopub_port": 55548
}
```

Here's how I start the IPython kernel:

```
$ ipython kernel --IPKernelApp.log_level=10 --IPKernelApp.connection_file=./ipker.json
```

Here's the node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var zmq = require('zmq');

var kernel = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("ipker.json"));

var shell_socket = zmq.socket('req');
var shell_addr = kernel.transport + "://" + kernel.ip + ":" + kernel.shell_port;
console.log("\nConnecting shell socket at " + shell_addr + "...");
shell_socket.connect(shell_addr);

shell_socket.on("message", function(msg){console.log("\nShell socket says:\n"); console.log(toString(msg))});

var header = {"msg_id": "12345", "msg_type": "kernel_info_request"};
var parent_header = {};
var metadata = {};
var content = {};
shell_socket.send(["","<IDS|MSG>","", JSON.stringify(header), JSON.stringify(parent_header), JSON.stringify(metadata), JSON.stringify(content)]);
```

The output I see on the console is:

Connecting shell socket at tcp://127.0.0.1:51314...

Shell socket says:

[object Undefined]

And here's the output from the IPython kernel. It seems to be getting the message and formulating a reply...

```
    $ipython kernel --IPKernelApp.log_level=10 --IPKernelApp.connection_file=./ipker.json
    [IPKernelApp] Config changed:
    [IPKernelApp] {'IPKernelApp': {'log_level': 10, 'connection_file': u'./ipker.json'}}
    [IPKernelApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/mgreenbe/.config/ipython/profile_default'
    [IPKernelApp] Searching path [u'/home/mgreenbe/Dropbox/Projects/node/zmq', u'/home/mgreenbe/.config/ipython/profile_default'] for config files
    [IPKernelApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
    [IPKernelApp] Loaded config file: /home/mgreenbe/.config/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
    [IPKernelApp] Config changed:
    [IPKernelApp] {'Session': {'key': ''}, 'IPKernelApp': {'log_level': 10, 'connection_file': u'./ipker.json'}, 'ProfileDir': {}}
    [IPKernelApp] Loading connection file /home/mgreenbe/Dropbox/Projects/node/zmq/ipker.json
    [IPKernelApp] Starting the kernel at pid: 3439
    [IPKernelApp] shell ROUTER Channel on port: 51314
    [IPKernelApp] iopub PUB Channel on port: 55548
    [IPKernelApp] stdin ROUTER Channel on port: 60304
    [IPKernelApp] control ROUTER Channel on port: 59733
    [IPKernelApp] Heartbeat REP Channel on port: 39868
    [IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
    [IPKernelApp]     --existing ./ipker.json
    NOTE: When using the `ipython kernel` entry point, Ctrl-C will not work.

    To exit, you will have to explicitly quit this process, by either sending "quit" from a client, or using Ctrl-\ in UNIX-like environments.

    To read more about this, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2049

    To connect another client to this kernel, use:
        --existing ./ipker.json
    [IPKernelApp] Writing connection file: ./ipker.json
    [IPKernelApp] Loading IPython extensions...
    [IPKernelApp] Loading IPython extension: storemagic
    [IPKernelApp] 
    *** MESSAGE TYPE:kernel_info_request***
    [IPKernelApp]    Content: {}
       --->    
    [IPKernelApp] {'parent_header': {'msg_id': '12345', 'msg_type': 'kernel_info_request'}, 'msg_type': 'kernel_info_reply', 'msg_id': 'c7c36418-4484-4ef7-868e-18c14fbe76be', 'content': {'protocol_version': [4, 0], 'language_version': [2, 7, 6], 'language': 'python', 'ipython_version': [1, 2, 1, '']}, 'header': {'date': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 5, 15, 50, 6, 437444), 'username': u'kernel', 'session': u'ab0783e9-ac7a-4c12-90ac-751687de6993', 'msg_id': 'c7c36418-4484-4ef7-868e-18c14fbe76be', 'msg_type': 'kernel_info_reply'}, 'tracker': , 'metadata': {}}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens in the terminal where the kernel is running? Does it get the message?

Comment: Added the terminal output to original post.

Comment: So the kernel is seeing the request and sending the output. Try making the shell socket with type 'dealer' instead of 'req' - it officially uses a router/dealer pair instead of req/rep. I'm not convinced that's the issue, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Tried the 'req' --> 'dealer' change. No effect on the output.